# OMNeT++/Veins problem using cSimpleModule

Tags: omnet++, veins

I'm implementing vanet with OMNeT++ 5.3 and Veins 4.7.1 but I'm experiencing errors that I can't solve.

The code:

```
public:
    SienaStatisticsAccess() { }
    SienaStatistics* getIfExists() {
        //Finds a module by its path.
        return dynamic_cast<SienaStatistics*>(simulation.getModuleByPath("stats"));
    }
```

The error:

```
'simulation’ was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should look like:

```
return dynamic_cast<SienaStatistics*>(getSimulation()->getModuleByPath("stats"));
```

Using this at least the `'simulation’ was not declared in this scope` will be gone.